# Xpages: is it possible to allow user to select multiple values and display dynamic result depends on user’s selection in Domino Designer 9.0.1?

Tags: xpages

I would like to ask is it possible to allow user to select multiple values and display dynamic result depends on user’s selection in Domino Designer 9.0.1?

We are required to develop a web application using xpages.

Here is is the background of web application:

- Each member has a current group
- Each group are required to join some specific activities
- Member can choose future group and check the activity is joined or not join

That means use member in current group’s latest activity status (joined or not join) to compare the future group (find which activity is joined or not join)

The sample pictures about the application will be like the following

For user's selection: the user can choose multiple members with related current group and the user can choose the future group for each member for the comparison.

[image]

After click the Submit button, the result shows to the user

[image]

Here is the question: is it possible to do this in Domino Designer 9.0.1?

The reason we ask is we haven't find similar sample on the internet yet and we don't know whether it is possible to do in the Domino Designer 9.0.1.

Grateful if someone can provide advice on this issue please. Thank you very much.

**Update:**

We apologize for our misleading question. We are absolutely not asking someone to write code for us.

We are not able to upgrade to Domino 9 at the moment and we are currently writing some code using 8.5.2.

However we have a concern that if we write a lot of complex code in the application, it will be a trouble for our colleagues to do the maintenance for program.

Also assume we write a lot of complex code in the application and the program works, what about if the user has new requirements base on the current function for the program? We believe the code will be much complex and hard for someone who handle this task to understand the logic of the program.

Thus, for the future development and the program maintenance. Is the latest version more flexible to develop and maintain or just not much difference to accomplish.

Sorry for the inconvenience we have made.

Thank you for your time.

**Update 2**

For the coding of the program, we have the following experiment.

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize

Print |Content-Type:application/text/html|

Print "<tr><td>Result<br></td></tr>"
Print "<br>"
Print "<br>"
Print "<table border = 1><tr><th>Member</th><th>Test 001</th><th>Test 002</th><th>Test 003</th></tr></table>"
Print "<table border = 1><tr><th>Activity</th><th>Joined</th><th>Joined</th><th>Joined</th></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 1</td><td>No</td><td>Yes</td><td>No</td></tr>"
Print"<tr><td>Activity 2</td><td>No</td><td>Yes</td><td>No</td></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 3</td><td>Yes</td><td>No</td><td>No</td></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 4</td><td>No</td><td>No</td><td>Yes</td></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 5</td><td>Yes</td><td>No</td><td>No</td></tr>"
Print "<tr><td>Activity 6</td><td>No</td><td>No</td><td>Yes</td></tr></table>"
End Sub
```

Those code just hard code only, it will open in html format.

Due to the data will change depends on user's selection, we cannot guarantee the size of the table and hard to define data to locate in which cell.

We are currently studying how to make those code dynamically, make it more flexible.

Thank you.

Comment: This is NOT a Domino specific question. This is a question about data structures. What have you tried, what didn't work? Don't expect others to write your code for you.

Comment: We are sorry for our misleading description @stwissel. We don't mean to ask someone to write code for us. As our company is using 8.5.2, we don't know whether this task can do in Domino 9, if Domino 9 is possible to do the task, we may try our best persuade our boss to upgrade the version. Thank you.

Comment: You could do such a task in Domino 4.5 if you wanted to. Update your question with the code that you tried - improves the chances to get an answer. It all boils down to how you store data and how you script it

Comment: The above code is LotusScript. Won't work in XPages

Answer (score 0):

The tool you need in XPages are custom objects either in JavaScript or Java (that's way less scary than it sounds) and one repeat control for the rows. If the number of columns are dynamic too, then you need 2 repeat controls.

The layout reminds me a lot of the table walker example (I wrote) as part of IBM's original [XPages 8.5.0 training exercises](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=F96D8FAF55207C64852575F5007593FB). You need to check them out.

In particular look at [Exercise 23](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=C8E56F876AF2315A852575F60076592B). The data source, multi value fields might not fit your case, but the dynamic table does.

Good luck and let us know how it goes.